# Network settings fail for ubuntu/xenial64 Vagrant box

Tags: networking, 16.04, vagrant

With the [Official Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64) Vagrant box image (on VirtualBox) I have problems with basic network settings:

My `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/xenial64'

  config.vm.define "xenial" do |server|
    server.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
  end
end
```

`vagrant up` result:

```
==> xenial: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifdown eth1 2> /dev/null

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-xenial
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Leaving the configuration to DHCP also does not work:

```
server.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
```

At the same time, the above configurations work for `ubuntu/trusty64` and `ubuntu/wily64` and unofficial [`gbarbieru/xenial`](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/gbarbieru/boxes/xenial).

Trying the command `/sbin/ifdown eth1 2> /dev/null` gives no results as the interface has different naming scheme (the main one is `enp0s3`).

Am I missing something obvious here or is the box just broken?

Answer (score 15):

The problem seems to be solved in the next release of vagrant: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7155

I tried another box from Jeff Geerling https://twitter.com/geerlingguy/status/723571293174427648?lang=fr and it worked perfectly for me. Jeff has done a lot of great work on Vagrant/Ansible so I guess it's the best solution before the release of the next version of Vagrant

Comment: I had the same problem with the official Ubuntu 16.04 box. After a few hours of trial and error I tried geerlingguy's box and it worked like a charm. The official Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box was also fine.

Answer (score 2):

Despite `ubuntu/xenial64` is the Official Ubuntu box, it [has some issues](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7155#issuecomment-228568200) regarding network configuration and is not an Vagrant issue as is explained in @Maxime 's answer.
So, as in the issue is mentioned, is preferred to use a [bento](https://github.com/chef/bento) box (mantained by the comunity and with Opscode Chef as leader of the project), which for this case would be `bento/ubuntu-16.04`.

Comment: "bento" boxes were also recommended by Vagrant's maintainer: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7155#issuecomment-228568200

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the network interface naming convention in new Ubuntu versions.  Your Vagrant VM failed to be provisioned, but you can still ssh to it (`vagrant ssh`).  There you'll see that there is no interface named `eth1` (you can use `ifconfig -a` or `ip link`).  In my case, I see the interfaces `enp0s3` and `enp0s8`.

As mentioned in [issue 6871](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6871)

> ... we need a way to detect the interfaces instead of having a static assignment...
>
> ... or convince ubuntu to change their cloud image.

At the moment, there is no clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, additionally to Maximes answer, you could change the GRUB commandline in your box until the new version is propagated.

Just go to `/etc/default/grub` and set the appropriate line to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"`
You have to change the `/etc/network/interfaces`to reflect the correct names (eth0...).

See the [documentaion of in certdepot for more Info](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-restore-old-network-interface-name/).

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue as discussed in the original question.

I am using Vagrant 1.8.1. and using the ubuntu/trusty64 box worked just fine, however, when I tried to use the ubuntu/xenial64 box, I faced the same issue.
A comment [in this issue thread](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/issues/970) brought me to a solution, which seems to work out.

I changed the line

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

in the Vagrantfile to

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10", auto_config: false
```