# vagrant up throws The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status error for Laravel Homestead

Tags: 16.04, ssh, vagrant

I'm trying to install Laravel Homestead on my Ubuntu 16.04. But I get this error when I want to run command "vagrant up":

```
milad@miladlenovo:~/Homestead$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifdown eth1 2> /dev/null

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:
```

Then my browser displays following error when I want to see my local site:

```
No input file specified
```

Comment: Seems there were a bug in last vagrant version in Ubuntu repository, new version downloaded from its official website works!

Comment: see  answer of two Questions http://stackoverflow.com/a/39320780/1908296 and https://askubuntu.com/a/761196/214624